# Problem when compiling OpenCV with ROS

Tags: ros, opencv, linking, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rosbuild to build a project with OpenCV and ROS. The OpenCV version is 2.4.9, built and installed from source. The ROS version is indigo.

When I include the nonfree module of OpenCV (has SIFT and SURF) in my project files, I got a linking error something like"libopencv.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to ocl::integral()" after I build the ROS package using the CMakeList.txt.

I noticed that the compilation information in the terminal shows the compiler is also trying to link to some existing OpenCV 2.4.8 libs in the directory /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgopencv*.so.2.4.8.

I realized that the OpenCV 2.4.8 might come with the CV_Bridge package when I install it. It seems the cmake is trying to link to some libs of 2.4.8 and also 2.4.9, which leads to some undefined reference. Another observation is that without ROS,  I am able to compile a project with OpenCV (using pkg-config).

It seems the problem is the co-existence of two versions of OpenCV. How can I make it only link to the version I choose? I used find_package in the CMakeList file, but the compiler always tries to link to both version.

Thanks you very much.
Rui

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205510/problem-when-compiling-opencv-with-ros/) by [RuiH](https://answers.ros.org/users/21934/ruih/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-21**:
Just to make sure: are you really using `rosbuild` or `catkin`?

**Comment by [RuiH](https://answers.ros.org/users/21934/ruih/) on 2015-03-21**:
I am using rosbuild.

**Comment by [Dinl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23729/dinl/) on 2015-08-31**:
Hi, I have the same problem when I use the nonfree module in ROS Indigo, have you found a solution for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My system info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- OpenCV 2.4.13
- ROS Jade

I have the same link error but fix by switching the following content in CMakeLists.txt

- ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} in target_link_libraries
- ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} in include_directories

OpenCV first, then catkin.

Hopefully this approach can resolve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [willSapgreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26619/willsapgreen/) with karma: 61 on 2016-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michalszczepanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/30024/michalszczepanski/) on 2017-04-14**:
I had the same problem, these procedure solve it! Thanks